# creating flask webapp with sql alchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pythonanywhere

I'm building a small webapp using flask and hosted on PythonAnywhere. The app is made of an `Exchange` class where several `Team` classes interact. Each user who logins is related to a specific `Team`. The app will have no more than 30 connected users at the same time although they will have to get info in real time. There is also an always-on task which will also need to connect to the database.

I'm using `sqlalchemy` to manage the database connections but I'm constantly getting either `(2006, 'MySQL server has gone away')` or `(2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query')`. Therefore I was wondering how I should manage concurrent connections within the app. I tried several configurations such as opening and closing the connections after every call in the flask app or even within every class method but nothing seems to work.

Should I make calls the database only from the flask app using for instance `flask-sqlalchemy` or are there other ways to achieve this?

Comment: So are you using flask-sqlalchemy right now? Because if you aren't, using it will probably be the solution.

Comment: Do you mean like moving all database calls from the classes to the web app and use flask-sqlalchemy?

Comment: It doesn't matter where you make calls to the database, it matters that you make calls using a Flask-SQLalchemy db. You only need to keep this in mind when initing your database, and if your database is init-ed as Flask-SQLAlchemy db, it will handle all kinds of funky errors and behaviour from there. Read [here](http://flask-sqlalchemy.pocoo.org/2.3/quickstart/#a-minimal-application)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your connections are timing out. Tell sqlalchemy to recycle connections after a time that is shorter than the timeout. Like this:

```
engine = create_engine('mysql+mysqldb://...', pool_recycle=280)
```